# Shared access signature in Azure Cosmos DB account?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible to add Shared access signature in Azure Cosmos DB account?
I can't find it in the navbar

[image]

Comment: You're looking for Connection String (under Settings" in your screenshot

Comment: unless you're looking for something with fine-grained permissions - which is a bit of a different discussion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi Shared Access Signature Authorization only applicable for Azure Storage Account. At this moment, it's not applicable for Azure Cosmo DB.

Reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delegate-access-with-shared-access-signature